# blob url in ie is not working

Tags: javascript, pdf, adobe

I want to dispaly PDF in IE10 or IE11 using blob url.

These I used to construct Blob URLs

```
var url = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
```

Blob url created using `createObjectURL()` is not able to generate proper blob url in IE and firefox. But works in Chrome.

But Adobe has removed PDF plugin support for chrome.

Is there any other way to display the blob url in other than `createObjectURL` method?

Comment: have same issue for images, if you fine solution please post it

Answer (score 2):

Look at [this link](https://mozilla.github.io/pdf.js/). They even have a viewer that can render blobs.

**Note:** for IE to work wrap the blob url in `encodeURIComponent()` before passing it to the viewer such as this:

```
'http://viewer.html?file=' + encodeURIComponent(blobUrl)
```